# Absolute reference all cell references in a Microsoft Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For a Microsoft Formula like this:

```
=IF(Data!H5=3,0,IF(Data!H5<=Data!H19,3,IF(Data!H5<=Data!H20,2,IF(Data!H5<=Data!H21,1,0))))
```

Is it possible to mass convert all the relative cell references to absolute references?

The desired formula would be:

```
=IF(Data!$H$5=3,0,IF(Data!$H$5<=Data!$H$19,3,IF(Data!$H$5<=Data!$H$20,2,IF(Data!$H$5<=Data!$H$21,1,0))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>F4</kbd> repeatedly while editing the formula to cycle among reference styles. You may need to select the whole formula to affect all the references in it.

In Excel:Mac 2011 (and possibly other versions for Mac), Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Selecting the whole formula is required before cycling through the F4 options.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac

Comment: @StatsSorceress: Added Mac keystroke to my answer